# unfortunately test1 has stopped

Tags: android

help please i want to run my app on the emulator but it doesn't run and keeps showing me unfortunately

```
package com.example.test1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button kh = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        kh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent kh = new Intent(MainActivity.this , kh.class);
                startActivity(kh);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe it is good practice to use the same name for more than one resource. If I said, "the problem is with `kh`" You would have no idea whether I was referring to the Button, Intent, or Class...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  In order for anybody to help you with this question, you're going to need to provide some more detail.

Answer (score 1):

you have `Button kh`...in the `onClick()` you send the intent to that button! `Intent kh = new Intent(MainActivity.this , kh.class);`

i think you want something else.

Comment: now its ok but when i click to go to the other activity it crushes again :s

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `kh.class` should be replaced with `<Target_Activity>.class` the activity which you want to launch..

```
Intent kh = new Intent(MainActivity.this , <Target_Activity>.class);
startActivity(kh);
```

Also make sure your `<Target_Activity>` is available in `<activity />` tag of Android Application's manifest file.

Comment: kh.class is the name of the activity i want to go to its ok now but the problem is when i click on the button to go to the next activity it crushes again !

Answer (score 1):

Create Activity same like `MainActivity` with different name say for example `SampleActivity` and call that

```
Intent kh = new Intent(MainActivity.this , SampleActivity.class);
startActivity(kh);
```

And include that activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".SampleActivity"
        android:label="@string/yourlabel"></activity>
```

It should work.

Comment: thaaanks it was all about not including the activity in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: ok whats the exact problem now could you update it